# SonarQube for Ruby Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I want to scan my Ruby rails application with Sonarqube so that i can easily integrate it with Some CI tool like jenkins, but in sonar available plugins, there is no plugin for Ruby. Any idea how i can scan ruby code in sonarqube ?

Answer (score 1):

For the time being, there is no analyzer for Ruby.